# Cake PHP model caching

Tags: cakephp, model

I'm sitting on this problem for quite a while!
I extended my user table inside my SQL database. It has now 17 columns instead of 16.
But when cake tried to this:

```
$loguser = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
```

$loguser returned me only the record the old 16 columns. The new one wasn't there. 
So I searched where cake saves the model but I wasn't able to find even a hint!!

So I pushed my project cloned it again from my gitlab into a new directory. 
I installed all dependencies by 'composer install'
And now the miracle happens! The 17th column of my record was there.

I went back to my origin project to try if I can reproduce this miracle by deleting the tmp and the vendor folder.

But no! after reinstalling the 17th column was still missing.

Now my question:

Does anybody know how to update my table model without reinstalling the whole project?

Comment: By default schemas are cached in `tmp/cache/models`, and removing that (as well as clearing the session in your case) should normally be all that is needed, unless you've made modifications to the model caching, or manually specified the fields to retrieve in your queries.

Comment: You are accessing session data, try logout and then login again

Comment: Or use `bin/cake orm_cache clear` on the CLI.